# "The cat that got the cream" - is there any innuendo?

Tags: british-english, idiom-meaning, north-american-english, innuendo

I think this is a [British idiom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like%20the%20cat%20that%20got%20the%20cream).

The American version would be, "The cat that killed the canary."

I was about to say this to a female friend, intended as a "well done" sort of compliment, specifically on something to do with her relationship, when my internal filter suddenly held back. Given there exist innuendo definitions of "cat" and "cream", and that she's American, not British, would the phrase have mis-communicated some innuendo?

Comment: Perhaps not to the extent of confusion to some Americans we were entertaining a few weeks ago, when they saw "Spotted Dick" on the restaurant's pudding menu!

Comment: It's my belief that the idiom is also known to Americans. I did not know about the canary version though.

Comment: no no innuendo at all, it is a simple simile.

Comment: Me neither @Mari-LouA.  The canary version sounds rougher and tougher (US/UK ?!) to me: If cream is consumed it's no major loss to anyone, just a gain for the cat; if a canary is consumed the cat may be content but that's a life lost...?

Comment: What innuendo are you thinking of? Just by saying 'innuendo' it now is guilty-looking. By 'cat' and 'cream' do you mean ... _snicker_ ... a hipster and his money?

Comment: @Mitch  You really want me to spell it out?

Comment: @Stewart please no. I'm just trolling you for fun. I don't think USans are more sniggery than UKans though which is your implication. Any red-blooded 13 year old son of a Buddhist monk could find innuendo in a bag of hammers... _snicker_

Comment: This seems opinion-based. But I'd consider it a mildly insulting thing to say, since it suggests someone who is smug and self-satisfied. That's probably more of an issue, but if you're willing to say something insulting to your friend then you're probably OK with an unlikely sexual connotation (would you refrain from all mentions of cats and cream?)

Comment: Related: [Why do cats love milk even though they are lactose intolerant](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/34247), [Should I feed my cat milk?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/780).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my 51 years of being British, and 50 years of speaking British English, I can safely say I have never come across any innuendo associated with the phrase "The cat that got the cream".

My understanding of the phrase would be that if two or more cats were given a saucer of milk from the same bottle, the one that got the cream (that floats at the top of the bottle) would be smug, because the cream is richer and tastier than the milk that follows.

For additional info, I am part of a family that thrives on innuendo, so I would consider myself a reliable source on this subject.  Now, if the phrase was "The pussy that got the cream", I might well snigger.

Comment: I think the OP refers to a possible innuendo to American ears, not British ears.

Comment: @user070221  Exactly. Knowing it's an established idiom defuses any snigger-potential. But if it's not known, and the context was specifically a relationship issue ....

Comment: Do Americans snigger at the word "cat"?

Comment: @PhilMJones  Good point. I've certainly had a Frenchman snigger at the word "chatte" when I used it innocently. Depending on the context, if it's re-doubled with "cream" ... I just wasn't sure

Comment: @Stewart but that's a different word, in French language and culture. They can snigger all they want at 'la vache' or 'concombre' but 'cow' and 'cucumber' are nothing to us. Or 'coq' is just a rooster to them but rude to English speakers.

Comment: @Mitch  Exactly. I am being cautious with my cultural ignorance. That's all.

Comment: @Stewart To actually give my personal opinion about the matter, no I don't hear any innuendo (also, not 13 yo). 'cream' is a rarer word culturally in the US, you give cats milk usually. The phrase sounds like some distantly familiar Beatrix Potter/Aesop fable mish-mash to me. A lot depends on context of the person, so it could well be bad in the wrong audience but self-searching, I can't remember anything like that from the past.But innuendo is vague and others might feel differently

Comment: @Mitch - "others might feel differently" - indeed, I'm not sure why you can't find innuendo in "cucumber", someone wrote a whole song with cucumber innuendo, called "the cucumber number" if you fancy looking for it. Also, the French word "coq" translates into BrE as "cock" or "cockerel".

Comment: Americans snigger at the *verb* cream.  Such innocense [joke]

Answer (score 2):

In my exit package from the oldest boarding school in England, my matron included the 'cream' phrase as the final line in a poem describing me; all the lines leading up to it made reference to my breeding, my idiosyncratic habits, and my morally mixed nature. From this experience, I would infer that there is no inherent sexual charge to the line, but certainly an implication of nefarious satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

[Collins Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/like+the+cat+that+got+the+cream) clearly  states  the difference between BrE and AmE usage,

***like the cat that got the cream  BRITISH***

or ***like the cat that ate the canary AMERICAN:***

> If someone looks like the cat that got the cream, they look satisfied and happy with themselves because they have been successful or done something they are proud of. `*Thanks a million,' he repeats, grinning like the cat that got the cream. Jules stands at one end, looking like the cat that ate the canary.*

while [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like%20the%20cat%20that%20got%20the%20cream) doesn’t cite any specific geographical   usage.

Google Ngram  shows a wider usage in BrE than in AmE of “[the cat that got the cream](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cat%20that%20got%20the%20cream%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ccat%20that%20got%20the%20cream%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccat%20that%20got%20the%20cream%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccat%20that%20got%20the%20cream%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0)”, so its reasonable to assume that the expression is also known in the U.S. where “[the cat that ate the canary](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cat%20that%20got%20the%20cream%2Ccat%20that%20ate%20the%20canary&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccat%20that%20got%20the%20cream%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccat%20that%20ate%20the%20canary%3B%2Cc0)”, is, however, more commonly used.

The idiom carries no innuendo, but given that it appears that the “cream” version is not popular in the U.S., whether it may be misunderstood and innuendo inferred very much depends on the person involved.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers on this page have already adequately dealt with the core of the question, by explaining that there is no innuendo in the phrase, both the question and one of the answers claim that the phrase is the British equivalent of the American expression *the cat that ate the canary*. As this claim may mislead those who come to this page in the future, it needs to be responded to.

As an American I'm not familiar with "the cat that got the cream," but if it merely means that the cat got a bonus through luck or effort (which is my understanding of the other answers), then it's not equivalent to "the cat that ate the canary": in that case, the cat, although doing something natural, has eaten another household pet and is, in the eyes of the owner, guilty. In many Looney Tunes cartoons, a cat named Sylvester tries to catch and eat Tweety Bird. They are both pets in the same house. "The cat that ate the canary" must be related to, or even stem from, these cartoons, I think.

Citations: [Definition 1 in Wiktionary for "cat that ate the canary"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cat_that_ate_the_canary) is "A person who appears self-satisfied or smug, especially while concealing something mischievous, prohibited, or private."  However, as one who has been speaking and listening to American English for about 63 years, and watching Looney Tunes for about the same amount of time :-), I'll say that the idiom as I have known it is closer to one quote in the entry for ["Cat That Ate The Canary" on "Historically Speaking"](https://idiomation.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/cat-that-ate-the-canary/) from the November 16, 1952, *Victoria Advocate* (accompanying a photo of a cat with an empty birdcage): "No wonder this nameless cat won’t look you in the eye. He is guilty as only a cat can be. He just ate not only one, but five canaries." All about Looney Tunes: The [Official Looney Tunes Site](https://www.wbkidsgo.com/looneytunes).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question "Is there (or could there be construed) innuendo in *the cat that got the cream*?". This is just a discussion on another part of the OP's post.

Comment: Also, we like researched and referenced answers anyway. And a quick look at the most likely reference ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like%20the%20cat%20that%20got%20the%20canary)) agrees with the OP and disagrees with you.

Comment: I agree with the answer that there appears to be no innuendo in "the cat that got the cream" but not that it is equivalent to "the cat that ate the canary." So I limited my answer to that aspect. If it should be a comment rather than an answer, I will be happy to change it if that's possible.

Comment: While it is true that this answer does not, strictly speaking, answer the question, it is a useful addition to this page (as it corrects what is arguably an error posted elsewhere on it), and too elaborate to be posted as a comment.